# Java constructor (anti-pattern) super-classing String

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor

The intention of the following design is to allow String values to be (in effect) subclassed to enable a number of what would be conflicting constructor methods to be established (e.g. the method signatures would be the same even though the parameter names would be different).

Kindly consider the following (non-functional) design:

Id Interface (an empty - marker interface)

```
public interface Id {}
```

Classes Interface (an empty - marker interface)

```
public interface Classes {}
```

Title Interface (an empty - marker interface)

```
public interface Title {}
```

Tool Class

```
public Tool(Id id) throws Exception
{
    this.span = new Span();

    this.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.ID, (String)((Object) id)));
}

public Tool(Classes classes) throws Exception
{
    this.span = new Span();
    this.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.CLASS, (String)((Object) classes)));
}

public Tool(Title title) throws Exception
{
    this.span = new Span();
    this.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.TITLE, (String)((Object) title)));
}

public Tool(Id id, Classes classes, Title title) throws Exception
{
    this.span = new Span();
    this.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.ID, (String)((Object) id)));
    this.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.CLASS, (String)((Object) classes)));
    this.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.TITLE, (String)((Object) title)));
}

public void Test() throws Exception
{
    Tool hammer = new Tool((Id)((Object)"hammer"));
    Tool poweredTool = new Tool((Classes)((Object)"tool powered"));
    Tool tool = new Tool((Id)((Object)"invention"), (Classes)((Object)"tool powered"), (Title)((Object)"define a new tool"));
}
```

The approach requires an interface per parameter "type" and the down cast / up cast from the specific interface "type" to Object and then to String...

I am uncomfortable with the approach and I'm hoping that there's a design pattern out there that would alleviate my desire to subclass String (solely for the purpose of constructor method differentiation)...

I have a variadic method that takes an arbitrary collection of name value pairs to provide an alternative to the fixed parameter constructors, but the constructors shown above are the most common combinations and therefore as a convenience to the programmer they are presently being contemplated as being provided...

Thanks!

Comment: How does this `(Id)((Object)"hammer")` work?

Comment: This can't possibly work. `java.lang.String` does not implement your custom interface `Id` so you could never cast `Id id` to `String`. (**You also cannot subclass `String`**) The compiler warns you about it, and you hack around the compiler message by casting to `Object` first, but that still doesn't make it a possible scenario. Why don't you run your code and tell us where you get the first `ClassCastException` ?

Comment: Using this approach produces a runtime error: but it illustrates the basic idea that's desired... (consider the code an illustration of the desired effect)

Comment: Consider writing statuc factory methods instead of a multitude of constructors.  That way you can distinguish your cases by *name* instead of (or in addition to) by argument types.  Choose good names and it will even be fairly easy to understand.

Comment: @Neoheurist You desire subclassing `java.lang.String` (although I don't see any subclasses in your code). This is not possible, so your question unfortunately doesn't make sense. Why don't you just make `Id`, `Classes` and `Title` a class and implement them? that's the OO way

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I did start a foray in that direction - my reluctance in taking the specific class approach was that I would need to repeat a lot of code - because `Id`, `Classes` and `Title` are ultimately just the tip of the iceberg... (e.g. these are three out of 117 possible attributes)...

Comment: @Neoheurist Is there any reason you couldn't create a superclass from which to extend each of these classes (`Id` et al.)? The superclass would presumably take a string in its constructor and require an abstract method defining what `Attribute.TYPE` that class is.

Comment: @Vulcan That is an option - my thought here was to simply develop my own String class that I could then subclass all day... but the idea of wrapping or recreating String in toto seemed like yet another misguided idea on my part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering how your constructors look I would suggest you to get rid of them and use a [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead:

```
class Tool {

    private Tool() { // Preventing direct instantiation with private constructor
        this.span = new Span();
    }

    ... // Tool class code

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private final Tool tool = new Tool();

        public Builder withId(String id) { 
            tool.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.ID, id));
            return this;
        }   

        ... // other methods in the same manner

        public Tool build() {
            // Add some validation if necessary
            return tool;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Tool tool = Tool.builder()
                .withId("id")
                .withClasses("classA, classB")
                .build();
```

Comment: Very interesting - I like the fact that the attribute (with methods) clearly indicate which attributes are being set...

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that constructors have a fixed name (that of the class), so they must be distinguished by parameter types, so you can't have multiple constructors with the same types but which interpret them differently.

There's the builder pattern (see other answer) or this - the factory method pattern:

```
// private constructor
private Tool() { }

// factory methods with same parameters but different names:
public static Tool forId(String id) throws Exception {
    Tool tool = new Tool();
    tool.span = new Span();
    tool.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.ID, id));
    return tool;
}

public static Tool forClasses(String classes) throws Exception {
    Tool tool = new Tool();
    tool.span = new Span();
    tool.span.addAttribute(new Attribute(Attribute.CLASS, classes));
    return tool;
}

// etc for other interpretations of a String
```

You could refactor this to make it a little cleaner, but this shows the essence of the approach.

Answer (score 1):

What I've used in the past is something like this:

```
public abstract class StringValue {
    private final String value;

    protected StringValue(String value) { this.value = value; }

    public String toString() { return value; }
}

public class Id extends StringValue {
    public Id(String id) { super(id); }
}

public class Classes extends StringValue {
    public Classes(String classes) { super(classes); }
}
```

This way, you get real, object-oriented types. This is particularly powerful if you have specific extra logic for each type (validation logic, conversion logic to represent the value in different ways for different systems integrated with, etc.)

And if you don't have a need for extra logic, it's just a few lines of code to create and extra type.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use static factory methods with different method names, as suggested in Bohemian's answer.

Given the hypothetical requirement that overloading cannot be avoided, we must provide different method signatures; more accurately, different signatures under erasure. Therefore it is necessary to define and use custom types like your `Id` etc.

One way is to have a method parameter just for overloading resolution, without caring for its value:

```
public Tool(Id id, String value){...}

new Tool( (Id)null, "hammer" );
```

It might look better with a constant for `(Id)null`

```
public static final Id ID = null;

new Tool(ID, "hammer");
```

---

If we require that the value must be carried in the parameter, you'll need wrapper types that wraps the values, as in Bolwidt's answer.

In java8, we could also use lambda expression to define the wrapper:

```
    public interface Id extends Supplier<String>{}


    public Tool(Id id)
    {
        String attributeValue = id.get();
        ...
    }

    new Tool((Id)()->"hammer"); 

    new Tool((Id)"hammer"::toString);
```